# window.open javascript problems jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

update: will use jquery if needed...
OK, I have almost everything working that I need...i just have a quick question. How can I put additional html/javascript into document.write function? I am experimenting with window.open (and yes, i know I should be calling up pages, but I want to do this all just using one page-- index.html) and I want to embed some images and another button but it won't work? What do I need to do to get this to work? (and where should the javascript for the button on window 2 go?)

Backstory:
There is index.html with 1 link and 1 button. Button opens window 1, link opens window 2. Window 2 has a button that can close window 1. the end!

index.html:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWin1()
{
myWindow=window.open('','','');
myWindow.document.write("<p>I want flower.jpg here</p>");
myWindow.focus();
}
function openWin2()
{
myWindow=window.open('','','');
myWindow.document.write("<p>I want bee.jpg here, a background color and a button
that will close window1</p>");
myWindow.focus();
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<input type="button" value="Window 1" onclick="openWin1()" /><br />
<a href="javascript:openWin2()">Window 2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you open to using jquery?

Comment: @glennferrielive yeah, as long as I can still just have one page...

Comment: anyone else have any help?? Will take pretty much anything...

Comment: does your code partially work in your environment?

Comment: everything works except i just don't know how to put in the <img> and button/new javascript information in document.write (when i do, i get obvious syntax errors) is there some other way i can do it?

Comment: put your `myWindow.document.write(' ');` in single quotes and your `img` will render fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
function openWin1()
{
    myWindow=window.open('','','');
    myWindow.document.write("<p><img src=\"http://www.digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/11/flower.jpg\" /></p>");
    myWindow.focus();
}
function openWin2()
{
    myWindow=window.open('','','');
    myWindow.document.write("<style type=\"text/css\">body{background-color:yellow;}</style><p><img src=\"http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_YGkSujzLG1g/S8eFOjiQ7yI/AAAAAAAAAA8/wSRi2dGDr-c/s400/bee.jpg\" /></p><input type=\"button\" onclick=\"window.close();\" value=\"close me\" />");
    myWindow.focus();
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/rLmCR/

Comment: oh wait, I just noticed that the button on window 2 closes itself. I was trying to have the button to close window one... what do i need to change to make that happen? thanks!

Comment: A window can only be closed by the window that opened it, and of course by itself.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments, I think your question really comes down to needing to know how to escape parentheses in a string.  The reason you are getting syntax errors if you do something like this:

```
myWindow.document.write("<p>I want <img src="myimageurl">flower.jpg here</p>");
```

is that the `"` is ending your string.  You can use the `\` character to escape the string, like this:

```
myWindow.document.write("<p>I want <img src=\"myimageurl\">flower.jpg here</p>");
```

which will not give you syntax errors.

Comment: thanks. new to javascript so i didn't remember to do that! lol

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var Window1, Window2;
function openWin1()
{
Window1=window.open('','','');
Window1.document.write("<p>I want flower.jpg here</p>");
Window1.focus();
}
function openWin2()
{
Window2=window.open('','','');
Window2.document.write("<p>I want bee.jpg here, a background color and a button
that will close window1</p>");
Window2.focus();
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<input type="button" value="Window 1" onclick="openWin1()" /><br />
<a href="javascript:openWin2()">Window 2</a>
</body>
</html>

To close Window1 from a button in Window2 use the below code 

function closeWindow2(){
 window.opener.Window1.close();
}

This button will be in Window2
<input type="button" onclick="closeWindow2()" />
```

Comment: I didn't down vote... don't know who did! thanks for your help